# Does Hyper-V 2008 R2 support external virtual networks on a wifi card?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, wifi

I've been using a "Windows 2008 Workstation" (google it) on my laptop.  I am aware of the workarounds to get Hyper-V to work on a wifi card.

But I'm wondering if Server 2008 R2 adds this capability?  Seems like something there would be some demand for.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by an [article by msdn's virtual guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/07/15/hdoalc-sorting-out-wireless-networking.aspx), they are not introducing this in R2.  The article explains some of the hoops he has had to go through on a laptop running R2.